# Binding array of ids to dynamically generated checkboxes in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

Good evening developers, so I have this issue when binding my checkboxes generated dynamically to values in an array. Basically I have the following in my **users.template.html** file:

```
<div *ngFor="let r of roles" class="checkbox">
   <label for="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ r.name }}" (change)="onRoleChange(r.name, $event)" [checked]="userRoles.includes(r.name)"> {{ r.name }}
   </label>
</div>
```

Basically what it does is updates the roles a user has based on the given checkboxes that are generated dynamically. Now the (change) works wonderfully but the [checked] is throwing an error saying the following:

***Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined***

I have no idea why because everywhere I looked it points me to use that kind of binding for this type of dynamic content. So any pointers would be awesome if you have them please. Thank you all in advance for any advice.

Comment: seems `userRoles` is not defined anywhere? Where does it come from?

Comment: I defined it at the start as ***userRoles: any[];*** and then initialized its data on ngOnInit() to get it filled.

Comment: Could you show a sample of its contents?

Comment: **[ "Admin", "CanGenerateTransactions", "CanSeeTransactions" ]** That is my user roles for example and I did a **console.log(this.userRoles)** to check that is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot call inherited methods of an object of a particular `type` directly in a template as per my understanding. You can call a component method instead which does that calculation for you.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ r.name }}" (change)="onRoleChange(r.name, $event)" [checked]="presentInUserRoles(r.name)">
```

> component

```
presentInUserRoles(role: string): boolean {
 return this.userRoles.includes(role);
}
```

Comment: This worked, don't know why it restricts it tho, it used to work like the other way before.

Comment: If you can show an example of how it worked before, may be I can try to point out the difference. You can of course refer to specific properties of an object 'within the template' but not call inherited methods belonging to its prototype.